# как сделать, чтобы при закрытии всплывающей формы ( нажатии на крестик), страница не обновлялась

Tags: javascript, html

Всем здравствуйте! Есть всплывающая форма (нажимаешь на кнопку  - появляется форма на странице), но при ее закрытии (нажатии на крестик) , страница перезагружается. Как можно это исправить?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show_popup").click(function() {
        $("#cooperation-form").appendTo('body').toggle();
        $("#all").css({
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "background": "black",
            "z-index": 5
        });
        $("#cooperation-form").css("z-index", 10);
    });
    $(".close-form").click(function(event) {
        $("#cooperation-form").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Return false или event.preventDefault. Или href атрибут поставить в #.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".show_popup").click(function(){   
$("#cooperation-form").appendTo('body').toggle();
$("#all").css({"opacity":0.5,"background":"black", "z-index":5});
$("#cooperation-form").css("z-index",10);
});
$(".close-form").click(function (event){
 $("#cooperation-form").hide(); 
 event.preventDefault();
});
});`

 `show_popup` - это кнопка, по которой вызывается форма. `all` - это див ко всей странице, сразу после `body`. После предложенного вами способа страница перестала перезагружаться при закрытие, но затемнение активно. Как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос и вставьте в него этот код.

Comment: А также осознайте что при появлении формы также появляется и див#all, с ним тоже надо что-то делать при закрытии формы.